# Theta Method for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-differences

[image]

I know the theta method is

$ u_{j}^{n+1} = u_{j}^{n} = (1+ \theta) r \delta x^{2} [u_{j}^{n}] + \theta r \delta x^{2} [u_{j}^{n+1}]$

However I am not sure how to prove that the above equation for the PDE

Comment: That is not really the theta method; it is just the theta method for the heat equation specifically. The theta method in general is for ODEs of the form $y'=g(y,t)$. It is given by $y^{n+1}=y^n+\Delta t \left ( (1-\theta)g(y^n,t_n)+\theta g(y^{n+1},t_{n+1}) \right )$. Your problem is an ODE of this form after spatial discretization.

Comment: Oh right, so should i try derive thid equation from scartch? I.e $  Ft[u_{j}^{n} ]= U_t $

Comment: Yes, you can get it from scratch; perform spatial discretization to convert to the form $y'=g(y,t)$ and then apply the general theta method formula.